# How to run Laravel Queue Job at AWS App Runner?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-queue, aws-app-runner

I am running a Laravel project on AWS app runner.
I installed the app by following this tutorial. https://qiita.com/sugimount-a/items/32da272685f03bfc943c
I added `php /app/artisan queue:work` at entrypoint.sh but the queue is not working.
Does anyone have an idea to run the Laravel queue at AWS app runner?
Thanks